# É possível reutilizar classes do domínio entre diferentes aplicações?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software

Alguns materiais inclusive recentes citam a possibilidade de reúso de classes do domínio por diferentes aplicações.

[Exemplo](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261026207_Coesao_e_Acoplamento_em_Sistemas_OO)

Esse reúso é viável?

Como ele se dá na prática?

Comment: São dois contextos que essa prática. No texto foi abordado a reutilização de classes  e POO(Programação Orientada a Objetos) e nesse caso você deve criar biblioteca de vínculos dinâmicos que seria uma .dll no Windows ou .so/.ldd em sistemas Posix(Unix/Linux/Mac e Windows com camada Posix) e nessa biblioteca,[Framework](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework) você compilaria classes cujo o escopo fosse comum a vários projetos, como a classe `Cliente` do exemplo que serve tanto para o projeto de uma locadora assim como o projeto de um banco. Para reutilizar a classe basta lincar seu framework.

Comment: O segundo contexto é banco de dados relacional. Onde você pode criar o mesmo conceito de framework mas ao invés de ter um arquivo compilado você teria um diretório catalogado de fontes em SQL contendo instruções em DDL(Data Definition Language)  que definiriam tabelas reutilizáveis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sim, é possível, mas ...

Bibliotecas e frameworks são exemplos concretos de reutilização de código. No Github não será difícil encontrar projetos que atendem domínios específicos e, consequentemente, reutilizar o código disponibilizado.

Por outro lado, contudo, a ideia de criar, por exemplo, a classe Produto "definitiva", ou a classe Pessoa, parece inatingível. Apesar do amplo interesse nestes conceitos, eles permanecem inexistentes nas bibliotecas padrão dos ecossistemas de Java e C#, por exemplo. Em *Building Evolutionary Architectures* (https://evolutionaryarchitecture.com/) há uma dica: estamos constantemente mudando, inclusive conceitos, adicionalmente, a perspectiva adequada para um dado domínio do conceito Pessoa, não necessariamente é adequada em outro. De fato, parece que sempre há uma diferença, um detalhe, que simplesmente impede a reutilização conforme o conceito foi definido originalmente.